# How does a session affine loadbalancer of Amazon AWS know that a session cookie is expired?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, session-cookies, load-balancing

If I use an HTTP load balancer with application-controlled session stickiness (in this case Amazon's AWS) the load balancer obviously has to remember all session cookies and their target instances in a map.
This global map will/must therefore keep the "session-cookie to instance" relations.

If the web app user decides to close the browser, the session will die silently on the app server after the session-timeout.

This means in turn that the load-balancer still has the "session-cookie to instance" relation in his global map. Since this mapping is now useless and the session cookie has no expiry date it cannot but should be garbage-collected (to free the resources).

My questions are:

1. How does a load balancer in general deal with this scenario without running out of resources?
2. How deals, in particular, an Amazon AWS load balancer with this scenario without running out of resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically an application-aware (layer 7) LB would *not* maintain a (large) map of sessions.  It might:

1. inject its own cookie into the first response to the client (and the
   client would re-send that on subsequent requests, so the LB could determine the
   target web server)
2. rewrite a well-known session cookie (such as
   JSESSIONID) by, for example, appending information to it that
   identifies the target web server (and which the LB would strip out before presenting to the web server on subsequent requests)

Key point is that the LB does not maintain the session to target map.  That information resides within cookies residing in each client.

I believe that AWS does #1 (using a cookie named AWSELB).

Comment: LB could do other things too, such as rewrite URLs within HTML page in transit to client which would be useful if the client did not support cookies.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it looks like it is #1. AWS set a cookie names AWSELB. This cookie is pretty large and obviously HEX encoded. I tried a simple decode, but it returned nothing useful. I guess it's also compressed in some way, to keep the size as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is correct, but when I choose "use application generated cookie" (e.g. JSESSIONID) for the AWS LB, the AWS LB does actually not set the AWSELB cookie. But JSESSIONID is set by the LB and it looks exactly as the cookie the App Server creates. Therefore it cannot contain useful instance routing information for the LB, unless the LB remembers this. Therefore the LB must store the JSESSIONID information **together** with the instance information somewhere/how to be able to route future request with he same JSESSIONID to the correct backend instance. Right?